# Can anyone identify this (allegedly) Ansel Adams photo of an ornate interior?

Tags: art, ansel-adams

My wife purchased this photographic print some years ago. It is signed "Ansel Adams" on the back (it could be a stamp, or it could be an actual signature in pencil).  The subject matter is a Middle Eastern interior, far different from the landscapes Adams is known for. The seller said it was a photo of the Ahwahnee Hotel in Yosemite, but that seems unlikely. Can anyone identify this photo for me?  Is it really Ansel Adams?  Any recommendations for other sources to check this out?
[image: Unidentified "Ansel Adams" Photo]

Comment: Have you tried going through [this list](http://www.anseladams.com/ansel-adams-photography/original-photographs-by-ansel-adams/do-you-have-an-ansel-adams-original-fine-print/)?

Comment: Nothing came up in a reverse image search http://tinyurl.com/l4fezph

Answer (score 5):

According to search results I was able to find, that is the Persian court of John Drum in San Francisco (not the Ahwahnee in Yosemite) as photographed by Ansel Adams ca. 1929. So, you may very well have an original Ansel Adams photograph or print on your hands.

https://www.mutualart.com/Artwork/Persian-Court-of-John-Drum--San-Francisc/8F31E97CB3C93A0BB0D6D5F65F94F844

Answer (score 3):

As previously noted, this is the Persian Court of John Drum in his penthouse apartment in the Freemont Hotel in  San Fransisco. There are at least 7 different images that were done by a young Ansel Adams on commission. I own this image as well as a couple of others. Mine has nothing on the back but there is a number and a signature below the picture. I have often wondered if more than one copy exists. They are quite rare, early examples of Adam’s architecture work.

Answer (score 1):

This photo doesn't look like much. Just a snapshot IMHO. A bit underexposed, not well composed with the cu-off chair in the bottom corner, lines are distorted (doesn't look like intentionally) and it's falling to the right. Assel Adams didn't just do landscape. We had an exhibit in town of Ansel Adams' Japanese Internment Camp photos so it's very possible hi also did architecture and other things. The only way to be sure is to bring it to an expert for an appraisal.