# Who is the photographer of this black and white photo of two female nudes standing over a pile of clothes?

Tags: history, photographer

A print was given to a friend long time ago and he vaguely remembers that he was told the artist was German. I feel like I have seen it somewhere before. I have tried searching by the below image in both Google and Bing and got no good result. Does anyone know some information about the photographer?

(Warning: NSFW image behind spoiler)

> [image]

Comment: I think famous photographs are relevant to the history of photography, and in scope for the site. That doesn't mean that _all_ "identify this image" questions are on topic, though — and unfortunately that sometimes comes down to needing to know the answer before asking....

Comment: It probably would help to describe the photo in the title and text, for the same reasons as http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions

Comment: I do acknowledge that this question can seem random but the artistic look of the photo and the fact that I feel like I have seen it before (probably in an art book) warrant my curiosity. I have searched for a discussion about this class of questions and found none; maybe this one can start one (or a tag). A similar question I found is this: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50692/can-anyone-identify-this-allegedly-ansel-adams-photo-of-an-ornate-interior

Comment: I edited the title to describe the photo. Thanks for the added warning. I was also wondering if the picture was NSFW.

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted. Seems like a perfectly reasonable question for a photography QA site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know anything about the photo but did do a bit of digging on Google.

Google Images has an option to search by image that returned the following results: [Here](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZitAeuBXzBt3WfpEj8wbHr9SyQR-oe3tilTGFzT7cT2A1m7IL2j3XXZPMk4eO2ef4U9wjT8dPUQXvQ3-Hy9ufmImE5ojB9eelzu1Vsc_1QmlZEp_1gmX4WVTk1cNdVAC7liOTVCv_1YhArAUW-Wl5DQ5w8cCEgCzeX9C91-XyGUVumozMD_1SGU8-pHIshArIEOtUP6VZnY3jmsaZ2MEu0k1Awe4TypGRSVpJhl8X1IMgQLmTp5JF4AE5FJcW-0we9g9S2orM3Q19wDrXEaS5kFmQKFWm7uM52bhiZIF6GXofLztCK77LwUjIH0ADTWheVFUpUyknrEIKSqarTjH-yvDnnYlQJtCQwIATCCiitm-eS_16ozY4_1QnMYvWdlLk7ZMUYimfBAPGHpc3F-ICGZdTUbEftIbsya3ftTezE35yN7Waf7hw2Cgw_1iBFGkEzvU3t_1G0ksAPqhoA3Vtp7r8l7V0PjOeNd_1AxdIun_1AEoPEtoBfzgaE4nd6yodS06M6H38hRvc3Z7iGnxGeyk8ZUa5_1IkscfAgVWUa_1Vchc0WE3rOrcDL43qg0cz1-xC0dOt4wq5laUMw-7zD0AfkfsyIcoiJLj9vH-SoWDyUb64UlRRie8R4PAXFq4-yna36NrpChsAXjC8PUdwBBXgCuKf_1F3S14id9Sah4mSZ62qk4XdukKCIOko1G6BU-BBwHH3LQ-YUNMwq1siaduvD3GMHbyKW0vRDrFGOuHIPmTi1oW58SrIcERx3ir4ygEZp7vtpiBYj0QG9zouxyE7SV5WWDC8AM-cpAnAuhNfTWhx9qH3Rdb0ghnD5Z8gUey_1aeaMs0H2REKeSu86JzWrioQVK2mx4YFziBl-VHt9ZgqIkWxTUojzgrbtEiks8tE4mtDvhab8TeHDPgt7niV3UYAGanKgQi4ErACbqr9wZh-HlS1nKNTY8-ANnJ9P5KqRMw5jE7o8gMd2IKGbcxoYqAYyTMx6S6oURQCfDTvmO5CERwhWAnc5ZHEoSKAbl2maDFm7nGSmdKXhkk8sRPZK7nnfdzxUjZjqgYL1FVVNfZ0P1c-7KL9tiHvzgVaKXWm1THhJ3gG7RI6pfq7LZxn8zTHmbPfummqVT2K0sY4c_1h08BhVjKC_172H3ACmNytCXBXZpQGq5ym7XH3PQRXcQR6nIWJeaLZm_1yIpj0MKlQxgTRerz9QqfX5ARrhTtRjp7-BwsfhfjN-1x177roEREKZqqHuxKGuBbl8bsdf7V3Faun1_1dnHoHMJRr6nPEMdeliR-bf6TD01tAw1GxB5dZ-645blhF1tX65y8NKhRlgjeAiKOaFseV3yTgAeuNKe21p8TgVgDc2C2MEXS9f_1eL1B2ygqNp_1ovJAR5JTb8OTBn8sDIA_1BS9rIG3B1rclc33j8_1fx1zAs4rf395YRuw8bpJUDnIn0DFHZ1mVJ5Yj-bp0c7QRZZmeDC0S9IWY)

This led me to what looks like an art auction website that is in German: [Here](http://katalog.auktionshaus-keup.de/de/t/nl.2012.19.nusser?PHPSESSID=hiah4vs2p90mk1u91tpjo7gob5)

Finally, the page did not resolve with the pictures, but it did have the alt text visible. Down at the very bottom one of the images has the text "Albert Watson 1942 - Two nude models".

Albert Watson is a Scottish photographer well known for his fashion, celebrity and art photography; more info at wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Watson_(photographer)).

For these reasons, I believe this image is from the artist: **Albert Watson** and is possibly titled *Two nude models*

Comment: Assuming your research is right, I'd say that passes the "notable photographer" test — http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Watson_%28photographer%29

Comment: Also http://petapixel.com/2011/10/06/the-story-behind-albert-watsons-portrait-of-steve-jobs/

Comment: @dpollitt It's so strange that I did the search a while ago but I got no similar images at all! Thank you so much for your leads! I will try to confirm this somehow.

Comment: Note that Google is not a search engine, per se, but an aggregator. Two identical "searches" on Google by two different individuals on different computers will give different results based on prior searches and meta information in the cookies formed in your browser.

Comment: And different results based on their stored dossier on you.